# Makefile compile only the first file one makefile instructions

Tags: c++, makefile

```
f1: f1.cpp f.h  
    g++ -c -Wall -g f1.cpp

f2: f2.cpp f.h  
    g++ -c -Wall -g f.cpp
```

This makefile does not compile `f2.cpp` to `f2.o`
It only compile the first file, any idea why?

Comment: You need a target (say) `all`, which has `f1` and `f2` as dependencies. And put that target (`all`) at top.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because make only [processes the first target (goal)](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#How-Make-Works). To do both add this as the first rule:

```
all: f1 f2
```

Answer (score 4):

Is this the entire contents of your Makefile? If yes, then you're missing the `all` rule.

```
all: f1 f2

f1: dependencies
    intructions

f2: dependencies
    intructions
```

Comment: i have one more problem, the dependencies does not work

Comment: What does not work exactly? And what do you expect? Dependencies on another rules should work automatically. Dependency on files require you to reference them on the rule instructions, let's say, `g++ -c -Wall -g f.cpp $<`. The `$<` identifier means _all dependencies_ of the respective rule.