# Makefile for m4

Tags: makefile

I want to convert a couple of *.in files to `*.H` file using m4 macro processor.

The second step is processing `*.H` files into `*.h` files with some config process.

I did not succeed in getting the appropriate Makefile.

My Makefile is as follows (simplified version):

```
SRCS= file1.in file2.in

%.H : %.in

      m4 $< >$@
      echo " $@ created"

%.h : %.H

      cp $< $@
      echo "$@ Refreshed"
```

Running make comes with "no targets"

How to get make to do something?

Comment: Check if **[this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24909730/makefile-compile-only-the-first-file-one-makefile-instructions/24909868#24909868)** helps you.

Comment: As @jweyrich hints at you haven't actually given make any explicit targets to build and there isn't even one for make to use as the default (since pattern rules don't count). `make file1.h` will likely work however.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide a default target in your Makefile :

```
SRCS= file1.in file2.in

all: $(SRCS:in=h)

%.H : %.in
      m4 $< >$@

%.h : %.H
      cp $< $@
```

Patterns (like %.h) are not valid default target, as make cannot infer which filename to try for this pattern.