# makefile to zip all folders in current directory

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to write a makefile which will compress (zip) all the folders in my current working directory. What I got so far is:

```
SUBDIRS := $(wildcard */)
ZIPS := $(addsuffix .zip,$(subst /,,$(SUBDIRS)))
$(ZIPS) : %.zip : | %
    zip $@ $*/*
dist: $(ZIPS)
```

*(from [Makefile: Generating zip files of all sub folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28844155/makefile-generating-zip-files-of-all-sub-folders))*

this does however only generate a zip file of the first folder in my current working directory (I would like to generate zips of all).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Makefile compile only the first file one makefile instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24909730/makefile-compile-only-the-first-file-one-makefile-instructions)

Comment: I tried adding all: but now i get *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.

Answer (score 0):

Just had to add all: $(ZIPS) as follows:

```
print-%  : ; @echo $* = $($*)
SUBDIRS := $(wildcard */)
ZIPS := $(addsuffix .zip,$(subst /,,$(SUBDIRS)))
all: $(ZIPS)
$(ZIPS) : %.zip : | %
    zip $@ $*/*
dist: $(ZIPS)
```